# How realistic is fund transfer in seconds or minute?

Tags: realism

Fund transfer be it from villain's side or hero's side, it is often depicted as a less-than-a-minute operation.

But in reality, fund transfer takes multiple steps. And when it's a 6 digit amount, it closely scrutinized.

So how realistic is fund transfer in minutes ?

Comment: In the UK, I can issue a transfer order from my phone and it happens within minutes or seconds. Not, sadly, a 6-digit number though.

Comment: Please don't assume that everything works just like you've seen, banks have different policies and practices. In addition to (ppossbly) being some bank(s) ploicy, "6 digit amount" is meaningless, currencies are not equal.

Comment: A lot of real-world scams function by getting the victim to cash a (bad) cheque and then forward part of the money elsewhere - the victim thinking the cheque is good just because the bank honored it immediately. But then it bounces later and the money disappears, leaving the victim out however much he forwarded.  Of course, the amounts usually aren't 6 figures, but the point is, just because the transfer goes through on-screen immediately that doesn't mean the validation was skipped.  It may just be postponed.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is so depicted because the underlying steps are irrelevant to the narrative. Besides, it would substantially lower the intensity of a dramatic situation if the villain digressed from the point, stopped their drama, and sat down with his cell phone waiting for the One-Time-Password to validate the transaction!